# How do I use a DNS service to change hosts with zero downtime?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm moving DomainX  from OldHost-dotcom to NewHost-dotcom. I'm using a DNS service, in an attempt to 
make the move with zero or near-zero downtime, but I don't know which of two approaches would be
better.

I really don't know what I'm doing. **Can you tell me which of the two approaches below is better?**

Thanks!

Given--
DNS setting at registrar:
 
ns1.OldHost-dotcom
DNS address for current host:
 
ns1.OldHost-dotcom
DNS address for new host: 
ns1.NewHost-dotcom
DNS address for DNS service:
 
ns1.NewDynamicDNS-dotcom
HostingSpace for OldHost-dotcom
oldhost-dotcom/myspace/
HostingSpace for NewHost-dotcom
newhost-dotcom/myspace/

The content of DomainX-dotcom will be available at both OldHost-dotcom and NewHost-dotcom during the transition process,
so overlap is fine.

## ****Approach_1****

****Pointing the New DNS Back at the Old DNS.****

Within the DNS service interface, I set the DNS address to the OLD host address...
then at my registrar, give the DNS address of my new DNS service.

Wait three days.

After the address of my DNS service successfully propagates through the host--
after DomainX seamlessly goes to the DNS service--
then have the DNS address inside my DNS service point to the new webhosting.

**Specifically:**

1) Inside the DNS service interface, change the DNS address to the OLD host address, namely,
ns1.OldHost-dotcom
2) At the domain registrar, change the DNS address to the dynamic service, namely,
ns1.NewDynamicDNS-dotcom
3) Wait three days for the domain registrar to fully link DomainX to ns1.NewDynamicDNS-dotcom .
4) Inside the DNS service interface, change the DNS address to the NEW host address, namely,
ns1.NewHost-dotcom

## **Approach_2**

****Redirecting the URL to Old Web Space****

Within the DNS service interface, I set a Web Redirect to the OLD hosting space...
then at my registrar, give the DNS address of my new DNS service.

Wait three days.

After the address of my DNS service successfully propagates through the host--
after DomainX seamlessly goes to the DNS service--
then have the DNS address inside my DNS service point to the new hosting space.

**Specifically:**

1) Inside the DNS service interface, set the Web Redirect address to the OLD hosting space, namely,
oldhost-dotcom/myspace/
2) At the domain registrar, change the DNS address to the dynamic service, namely,
ns1.NewDynamicDNS-dotcom
3) Wait three days for the domain registrar to fully link DomainX to ns1.NewDynamicDNS-dotcom .
4) Inside the DNS service interface, set the Web Redirect address to the NEW hosting space, namely,
newhost-dotcom/myspace/

Again, I've got no idea which of these approaches would work better for my zero-downtime goal, 
or if either of these approaches is correct, or
if there's some third approach that would work even better.

I'd really appreciate it if you could show me a good approach!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this much more complex than it needs to be. Simply update the A records in your current DNS hosting service to point at the new host.

Your DNS hosting service will often be your domain registrar. If your web old host is providing DNS services move your DNS service back to your registrar in advance of your server move, a free DNS provider like CloudFlare, or a paid DNS provider like AWS Route 53.

Comment: >Simply update the A records in your current DNS hosting service to point at the new host.
<br>Thanks-- would that preserve paths?<br> DomainX currently has attached to it some/long/paths/with/scripts/and/stuff... would these still work when DomainX is re-pointed, via the domain registrar, from nnn1.nnn.nnn to nn2.nnn.nnn?

Comment: For 99.9% of cases Cloudflare with get you there. The least possible TTL is 60 secs over there. Its important to lower the TTL before transition and wait till the previous TTL value to let that propagate.

Comment: @ziff paths are irrelevant to DNS. DNS is how domain names are mappy to servers. I use CloudFlare for this, I've done it many times, with no issues. I suggest you read up on what DNS is and how it works.

Comment: [_italic]>For 99.9% of cases Cloudflare with get you there. >I use CloudFlare for this[_italic] I've already purchased use of a DNS service, but have not applied it yet; the registrar currently points to the OldHost's DNS. I would like to have the DNS more flexibly controlled, via the DNS service, with zero downtime. Given this, should I repoint the DNS address or the IP numbers/hosting space?

Comment: Like I said, you really need to do some reading on how DNS works. Your steps are 1) Migrate DNS to CloudFlare 2) Update domain registrar to point at CloudFlare DNS servers 3) Change your A records when the new host is ready

Comment: By "migrate DNS," do you mean (a) copy the existing DNS records (as stored at OldHost) to CloudFlare; or (b) within CloudFlare, point to the NewHost IP; (c) within CloudFlare, point to the NewHost webspace; (d) something else?

Comment: Re "migrate DNS", when you set up CloudFlare it copies all your existing DNS records. This gives it the capability to replace your current DNS server. Once you change your name server settings it starts actually doing the job. Suggest you initially turn off caching, ie change orange cloud to grey, in the DNS section. If you want caching / CDN turn it back on after some testing, but default settings are fairly safe.